# How do I get rid of the "The metatable is locked" thingy on Lua? And how do I add getrawmetatable?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want for string to be able to use the `%` operator in Lua, but whenever I do this:

```lua
getmetatable("").__mod = function(a, b)
        if not b then
                return a
        elseif type(b) == "table" then
                return string.format(a, unpack(b))
        else
                return string.format(a, b)
        end
end
```

errors

```
attempt to index string with '__mod'
```

`debug.getmetatable` doesn't work

```
debug.getmetatable("").__mod = function(a, b)
        if not b then
                return a
        elseif type(b) == "table" then
                return string.format(a, unpack(b))
        else
                return string.format(a, b)
        end
end
```

errors `attempt to call a nil value`

So I tried `getmetatable("")` and it returns `"The metatable is locked"`.
How do I get rid of the `"The metatable is locked"` thingy in Lua?
I didn't anything to the string metatable. I also found out `debug.getmetatable` is `nil` instead of a function.

This thingy also happens to workspace `getmetatable(workspace)` and the game global `getmetatable(game)`

I found out synpase got rid of this: https://x.synapse.to/docs/development/objects_mts.html
with a function called `getrawmetatable`?
How do I add `getrawmetatable`?

Answer (score 5):

If `debug.getmetatable` doesn't exist, then you must not be running your script from the standard Lua environment. Instead, you're running it from an application that has embedded Lua into it.

Such an application has *total control* over what it allows you to access from Lua. So if it has removed `debug.getmetatable`, and has removed the ability to retrieve the string metatable via `getmetatable` (by giving the string metatable a `__metatable` field that is a string), there's nothing you can do from Lua itself to modify said metatable.

Also, unless you have control over the environment (ie: you are the *author* of the program that is embedding Lua, but if you are, you already know what you did), it's generally bad form to manipulate basic aspects of Lua like the string metatable. Users of Lua in this environment will have no idea what doing `%` to a string is supposed to mean.

Just type `string.format` like everyone else.